# Stop Terminal from saving commands

Tags: command-line, 16.04, system

When using terminal, it saves the previously executed commands. When I press the Up arrow button, it tells us that which commands I have run previously.

Suppose, I am using my friend's system and start using it's command-line. Now, my friend will get to know what commands I have been running. 
But I don't know want him to know this.

Is there a way I can stop terminal from saving these commands for the current session ?

(Just suppose this scenario for this question. I am not a cheater)

Comment: For a non persistent solution do the following in the terminal:  `unset HISTFILE`

Comment: " But I don't know want him to know this."
 If it is his system I consider this abuse of his system.

Comment: what will that do @Carl ? please explain.

Comment: @Rinzwind: In my opinion it can be matter of privacy.

Comment: @luv.preet: as a alternative to what carl said, you can use `history -c` before closing the terminal too.

Comment: Examine the HISTFILE variable.  It will remove this variable.  Therefore it wouldn't be updated.

Comment: @Ravexina never. The system is owned by someone else. So if you download porn with children in it HE goes to jail if someone finds out. Not you. You should have zero privacy on someone else his system.

Comment: @Rinzwind: I didn't thought of that.  But I think If you don't trust somebody and you think he/she may abuse your system or do pretty bad and evil things with the system as you said.  you shouldn't let him/her to use it in the first place. Because it's hard to prove that somebody else did it, even when you got the logs, history, etc.

Comment: okay,  stop this privacy thing.  I couldn't think of a different scenario. Showing friends some skills is a cool thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Several things you could do.

#### 1. Type a space in front of each command you run.

It's tedious, but putting a space in front of your commands will keep them from being saved to the bash history.

#### 2. Set a Cronjob to delete .bash_history every hour

Your terminals historical commands are stored in `.bash_history` in your home directory.  If you delete the file, it will effectively remove your history.

First create the script to remove the `.bash_history` file:

```
nano ~/script.sh
```

and add:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm /home/user/.bash_history
```

then run:

```
chmod 775 script.sh
```

to make script executable and run:

```
crontab -e
```

and add `1 * * * * * /home/user/script.sh`.

Then exit and save, and it should delete your history every hour.

#### 3. Run `unset HISTFILE`, as @Carl suggested.

Just run it before exiting the terminal, and it will not save those commands that you ran in the last session to `.bash_history`.

Comment: It's probably worth distinguishing which solutions disable the collection of history (i.e. the commands would not be visible in the current session) versus disabling recording it to, or subsequently modifying the contents of, the history file. FYI you might want to consider adding `set +o history` / `set -o history`.

Comment: typing a space is an easy thing, this will work. So, this does not let a command to be stored in history, right ?

Comment: That's right.  Just type a space in front of the command and try pushing the up arrow after running the command: you won't see anything.

Answer (score 2):

A classic approach to prevent saving the bash history is removing `.bash_history` and replacing it by a link to `/dev/null`:

```
sudo rm ~/.bash_history
sudo ln -s /dev/null ~/.bash_history
```

Now no history would be saved for the current user.